# Passing boolean Vue prop value in HTML

Tags: vuejs2

I am fairly new to Vue and have started with a project with [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli).

I am looking into conditional rendering based on a prop sent from parent.

**Home.vue** *(parent)*

```
<template>
    <Header have-banner="true" page-title="Home">

    </Header>
</template>

<script>
    import Header from "./Header";

    export default {
        components: {
            Header,
        },
        name: "Home",
        data() {
            return {
                header: "Hello Vue!",
            };
        },
    };
</script>
```

**Header.vue** *(child)*

```
<template>
    <header>
        <div v-if="haveBanner == 'true'">
            ...
        </div>
            ...
    </header>
</template>
```

I have looked at another [conventional](https://vue-school.com/conditional-rendering#v-if-and-v-else) way to achieve this but vue-cli renders templates differently.

As passing the prop in the HTML markup, the prop `haveBanner` evaluates as a string and, therefore, even if I did:

*Parent*

```
<Header have-banner="false"></Header>
```

*Child*

```
<div v-if="haveBanner"`>
    ...
</div>
```

That `<div>` would still display and, because of this, I am having to do an explicit check to see if it evaluates to `'true'`. I am not a fan of this due to possible issues with type coercion and I am thrown a warning with a type check (`===`) saying:

> Binary operation argument type string is not compatible with type string

Is there a way to for either the child to evaluate this prop as a boolean or for the parent to pass it as a boolean in the markup?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If passing in JS keywords such as boolean values or references to variables, you will need to use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) (or `:`), i.e.:

```
<Header v-bind:have-banner="true" page-title="Home">
```

This will have the effect of binding the boolean `true` to the prop, not a `"true"` string. If you are not using `v-bind`, the `haveBanner` prop will *always* be truthy because it is a string of non-zero length, no matter if you assign `"true"` or `"false"` to it.

Friendly hint: HTML tags are not case-sensitive, so you might want to use `custom-header` or `my-header-component` instead of `Header`:

```
<custom-header v-bind:have-banner="true" page-title="Home">
```

See proof-of-concept:

```js
Vue.component('custom-header', {
  template: '#customHeader',
  props: {
    haveBanner: Boolean,
    pageTitle: String
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom-header v-bind:have-banner="true" page-title="Home"></custom-header>
  <custom-header v-bind:have-banner="false" page-title="Home"></custom-header>
</div>
 
<script type="text/x-template" id="customHeader">
    <header>
        <div v-if="haveBanner">
          <code>haveBanner</code> is true!
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <code>haveBanner</code> is false!
        </div>
    </header>
</script>
```

Pro tip: Use `:` shorthands to make your template more readable, i.e.:

```
<custom-header :have-banner="true" page-title="Home">
```

Answer (score 4):

To use a `Boolean` type as a prop, you have to use `v:bind`

```
<Header v-bind:have-banner="true" page-title="Home">
```

or using a short syntax

```
<Header :have-banner="true" page-title="Home">
```